# SSRS: Cannot view home folder in browser, especially Internet Explorer as administrator

Tags: reporting-services

I've been trying to access SSRS reports through Internet Explorer as ADMINISTRATOR but still could not load the home folder. Although I don't have any reports yet since it is a fresh install, I could not load the folder contents and I get this error message:

> Could not load folder contents. You are not allowed to view this folder. Contact your administrator to obtain the necessary permissions.

[image: click this link to see screenshot]

I've already tried all possible fix such as re-installation, using different versions, etc. but to no avail.

Do any of you know how to fix this? Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you go into the `Settings > Site Settings > Security`?

Comment: Nope, I only got Settings > My Subscriptions. No other sub menus under Settings which is baffling.

Comment: Go into the `ReportServer` database and see what `login name` is set to the `dbo` user name. Then login as that user to the ReportServer and add users to the site settings security.

Comment: As I have checked, the login name for dbo is my windows account, which is an admin account. When you mentioned "Then login as that user to the ReportServer and add users to the site settings security.", do you mean to say access http://localhost/reports in browser? I did and still the same results... huhu